# Web API issue with stored procedure using ASP.NET Model and AJAX POST

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm running into an issue with a parameter being null or not provided. The following error is below:

> Procedure or function 'Sp_Warning_Add' expects parameter '@Full_Name', which was not supplied.

My ApiController:

```
    Database_Access_Layer.Db dblayer = new Database_Access_Layer.Db();

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult AddWarning([FromBody]WarningData Warning)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            dblayer.Add_Warning(Warning);

            return Ok(Warning.licenseNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e);
        }
    }
```

My model structure:

```
public class WarningData
{
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string licenseNumber { get; set; }
    public string warningDateIssued { get; set; }
    public string warningLocation { get; set; }
    public string warningOfficer { get; set; }
    public string warningDetails { get; set; }
}
```

My DB access layer:

```
public class Db
{
    // Add Warning Procedure
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    WarningData Warning = new WarningData();

    public void Add_Warning(WarningData Warning)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Sp_Warning_Add", con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Full_Name", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.fullName));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.warningDateIssued));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Details", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.warningDetails));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Unit", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.warningOfficer));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Location", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.warningLocation));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Fine", "0");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Jailtime", "0");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Warrant_Active", "No");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Charges", "Warning");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License_Number", Encoder.HtmlEncode(Warning.licenseNumber));

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE proc Sp_Warning_Add
    @Full_Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Date NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Details NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Unit NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Location NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Fine NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Jailtime NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Warrant_Active NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Ticket_Charges NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @License_Number NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tickets 
    VALUES (@Full_Name, @Date, @Ticket_Details, @Ticket_Unit, @Ticket_Location,
            @Ticket_Fine, @Ticket_Jailtime, @Ticket_Warrant_Active,
            @Ticket_Charges, @License_Number)
END
```

My AJAX Call:

```
$('#createWarningBtn').click(function (event) {
    var warningFormSerialized = jQFormSerializeArrToJson($("#warningForm").serializeArray());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/Civilian/AddWarning",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Warning: warningFormSerialized }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        failure: function (data) {

            alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
            alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            civTickets(data.responseJSON.d);
            $('#warningForm').dialog('close');
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

What exactly am I doing wrong for the values to not be present? Running this AJAX call to a WebMethod works, however when I use an APIController this way it won't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was in the AJAX call.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Warning: warningFormSerialized }),
```

Should be:

```
data: JSON.stringify(warningFormSerialized),
```